# How to calculate X days value with a daily decrease in other variable?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Lets say daily profit p is 1 USD. Lets say one will work for 5 days (d). Daily profit decrease (z) is minus 10% from the profit of previous day. I want user to be able to input p, d and z values and Excel to calculate total profit. Like 1*100% + 1*90% + 1*81% + 1 *72,9 + 1*65,61 =???
How do I derive formulas like this in Excel?

Comment: What have you tried? Please supply some sample data along with what you have already tried and what results you would expect.

Comment: I only imagine how to program it with Java or with certain number of rows in Excel, but I can't imagine how to fullfill such function in Excel. I have used very superficially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a geometric series:

[image]

In your case, x is 1-z and n is d-1. If p, d and z are in A1, B1 and C1, Then the total profit is

=A1*(1-(1-C1)^B1)/(1-(1-C1))

Comment: Thank you, I'll test it out once at PC and accept your answer then

Comment: So X is equal to 1-z because of incremental decrease. And n is d-1 because decrease starts from the second day. If condition would be changed to 10% drop each second day, I guess I could simply change d-1 to (d-1)/2

Comment: That would be a 5% drop each day.  If you mean the *same* profit on days 1 and 2, then 10% less on days 3 and 4, etc., then that won't work.

Comment: No, I mean 100% on 1st day, 90% on 2nd and 3rd day, 81% on 4th and 5th day and etc.. That is change happens only every Nth day (this case every 2 days).

Comment: That gets a bit tougher.  In that case the series is 1 + x + x + x^2 + x^2...  So it's really 1 + 2x + 2x^2 etc.  Then x is 2*(1-z) and n is (d-1)/2 but d has to be an odd number.  I *think* this is right - needs to be tested.  No this isn't quite right.

Comment: No worries, I'll get by with gradual decrease each day

Comment: The series above is 2 x (the original series) -1. So I think you can get to it that way.  Again, n is (d-1)/2 and must be odd.